# Apply OData parameters ($filter, $orderby,...) to List<T>

Tags: c#, odata, iqueryable

Problem:

I have a collection List I need to filter this collection by OData parameters ($filter, $orderby etc) Is there something I can use which will do what I want?

Origin:

SharePoint REST API has a threshold limit (5000 items) and when list has more items exception is thrown. Thst is why this won't work:

```
HOST/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList?$filter=FieldName eq 'foo'&$orderby=OtherFIeld asc
```

We can get all items but we can't use OData parameters like this:

```
HOST/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList
```

In response we will get __next property where we can find url we will use to take next page of data and it will looks like this:

```
HOST/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList?$skiptoken=4988
```

So this is how we will get all items. Now I need to apply OData parameters from initial request to filter results on my side. I do not have idea how to do that.

Comment: Here it is http://linqtoquerystring.net/examples.html

Comment: I didn't quite get your last sentence. Is it that the filter results contain more than 5000 items which get the exception and you would like to find a way to get all filtered items?

Comment: @YiDing No and yes. Any OData filtering will fail while SP list has more than 5000 items (you can play with indexes). That is why I fetch all items, store them in List<T>, and apply original OData parameters to that list. In result I get only those items I need.

Comment: What about using "HOST/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList?$filter=FieldName eq 'foo'&$orderby=OtherFIeld asc & $top=5000"?

Comment: $top does not help here... threshold limit is not only for number of returned results but for number of items on list. that is why you can't $orderby or $filter more than 5000 items.

Comment: @ŁukaszAdamus, why would sharepoint mind if there are more than 5000 items on the server if only 10 for example are sent?

Comment: @gdoron it really doesn't matter how query will be limited by $top & $skip params. Before $top or $skip will be applied, SP must use other params like $orderby or $filter.

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878035/breeze-webapi-how-to-combine-queryresult-with-odataqueryoptions-to-return-inlin), you can do something like this:

```
public async Task<Object> GetMyList(ODataQueryOptions<MyObject> options = null)
{
    // Get your list from SharePoint
    List<MyObject> myObjects = GetMyObjectListFromSharePoint();

    // This will apply the OData query parameters 
    // to your IQueryable object but won't execute the query
    IQueryable query = options.ApplyTo(myObjects.AsQuerable());

    // This will execute the above query 
    // and return the new list of MyObject
    List<Object> result = await query.ToListAsync();

    // Do post result actions

    return result;
}
```