# Breeze.net : apply ODATA filters before the endpoint returns

Tags: c#, nhibernate, odata, breeze

I use breeze.net to handle ODATA queries. This is my endpoint :

```
public IQueryable<Car> Cars()
{
  IQueryable<Car> cars = this.context.Cars.Where(x => x.Color == "Blue");

  return cars;
}
```

If filters or pagination is passed from the client, they will be applied correctly to the IQueryable when the above method returns.

However I'd like to apply them BEFORE it returns because I'd like to call ToList() and do some processing on the data:

```
public IQueryable<Car> Cars()
{
  IQueryable<Car> cars = this.context.Cars.Where(x => x.Color == "Blue");

  var myCars = cars.ToList()

// do stuff

  return cars.AsQueryable();
}
```

Obviously the above works but none of the filters/pagination passed from the client are applied. Is there a way to achieve this ?  (FYI I use NHibernate so the NHContext, not EntityFramework)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WebAPI OData support? If that's the case I think you could do something along these lines:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Car> YourGetCarsWebApiEndpoint(ODataQueryOptions<Car> options)
{
    var queryable = yourCarsRepository.Cars();

    // Explicitly apply OData options to queryable:
    queryable = (IQueryable<Car>)options.ApplyTo(queryable);

    var cars = queryable.ToList();

    // Do stuff:

    return cars;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but no, I don't. I use breeze. I had already tried your solution but it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, guess you may have already checked these for ideas as well, but just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705932/manually-applying-odata-query-options-using-breeze-and-still-return-inlinecount

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, I did not know about this ! Thank you. However I use  `Breeze.WebApi2` instead of `Breeze.WebApi` as in the example. And there is not such method as `Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.ApplyQuery`. I will ask on their github unless they answer here..

Comment: actually their github appears to be frozen and no support is provided... I hope they can answer here.

Comment: There is though, wouldn't it be this one?: https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/2cfa44966d313fa0c2f7a9f78c8704e11541cdae/AspNet/Breeze.WebApi2/QueryHelper.cs#L53